# when is better to save the result of a function instead of calling it again?

Tags: java, optimization, memory-management

Let's say I have this function in java

```
    public static Character firstNonrepeatedChar(String in) {
            int[] repeated = new int[256];

            for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
                repeated[i] = 0;
            }

            // First time calling in.length()
            for(int j=0; j<in.length(); j++){
                repeated[in.charAt(j)]++;
            }

           // Second time calling in.length()
           // I could have used "int length = in.length() and use this variable in this second loop"
            for(int j=0; j<in.length(); j++){
                if(repeated[in.charAt(j)] == 1)
                    return in.charAt(j);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

As you can see I have used in.length() twice. Another approach could be saving the in.length() once in a variable and use the variable. can someone tell me how big of difference this makes?  I know if I wanted to use that value like 100 times I should keep the value in a variable but in this case we are deciding between just one more function call or using an integer variable.

Comment: The `length()` method just return a value of a field. So it's O(1). The only use case I see is for maintability. If you want to run your loop for the half of your String, you will just have to change the value of the variable used to store the length instead of making these changes in all the for loop you wrote.

Comment: I believe that in your case time costs will be virtually identical. In such case I would opt for readability, i.e. using method call twice.  I think storing the value makes sense when a method call tends to be slow, and we are guaranteed that the preserved value could not possibly change in between, and there is a reason to doubt that Java optimizer wouldn't handle it on its own.

Comment: [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue.size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#size%28%29) is one example where you should think twice before calling that in a loop since that's O(N)

Comment: +1 You stole my question :)  (not about length() but in general: why people usually put it in `for()` instead of saving and using the value?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally, optimize when you can measure that the optimization 1) is beneficial and 2) is worth it. By worth it, I mean that a decrease in readability warrants the increased performance. Point 1 means that your change may be detrimental, or may just not do anything.

For example, adding a local variable will make your method's stack larger, which may be worse than the runtime gain in extreme environments. Also, `String.length()` simply returns a variable's value, so not calling the method does not save you much. Your JIT may (and probably will) optimize the loop condition anyway, meaning that your optimization was not actually beneficial.

Comment: And the general rule with modern languages is to avoid premature optimization.

Comment: Note that "measure the optimization" should be in the context of the actual code, not a micro-benchmark. If the code being optimized is too small a part of the application for changes to make a measurable difference, don't optimize it.

Comment: @ PM 77-1 Why people insist on calling things like this premature optimization? If one writes a function and can do something in 2 equivalent ways, why not to choose a way which can save even a tiny split of nanosecond? (Of course, providing both ways are correct)

Answer (score 3):

The JIT will inline simple methods like `length()`  If you want improve performance you would have to look at different algorithms.

Something you can do is assume an array is already full of 0's so you don't need to zero it out.  Note: you might have characters > 255.

Also I would return a `char` as you cannot have a `null` value.

Comment: Does this inlining allow you to avoid repeated execution? How can it predict the value didn't change and who checks the correcness?

Comment: @Leeor In this case, `length()` returns a `final` field.

Comment: Also, `String` is final, so the method can't be overridden

Comment: @SillyFreak The JIT can optimise dynamically based on the class actually used.  If the class was sub-classed it can still inline the method.

Comment: True (I guess?), but it's even easier this way because the JIT doesn't even have to check the runtime class before branching to the inlined code, right?

Comment: True, but I don't think it even needs a branch, it just inlines the field.

Comment: in case there is no repetead Char I have to return null or throw some kind of exception. I think returning a null is a good choice for which I had to use Character not char as the function return type!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the function you are calling. Since you are calling `String.length()`, it is perfectly fine to call it more than once in the same context, even if the return value is not expected to change.

However, it is considered best practice to cache function return values in variables, especially for complex functions. In your case, there isn't much of a difference.